# How to control the Bit Rate (mbps) of Raspberry Pi Access Point

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, hostapd, access-point

I have two "Raspberry Pi 3 B+" boards which are required to be connected. One Raspberry Pi is configured as Access Point (AP) and the other one is just a Client. When both are connected, I write the command "iwconfig" on the Client side which shows the specifications of the network with which the Client is connected to(AP). In the specs i see "Bit Rate = 72.2 mbps" which varies after sometimes. Sometimes it shows 65 mbps sometimes 48 mbps and then again 72.2 mbps. How can i make this Bit Rate limited to 11 mbps? I have tried changing the modes of AP from its hostapd.conf file. I have tried

(1)

```
hw_mode=g
```

(2)

```
hw_mode=b
```

(3)

```
hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
```

But nothing has changed, the Client is still showing Bit Rate = 72.2 mbps which varies after sometimes.How can i make this Bit Rate limited to 11 mbps?

I am using "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)".

Comment: I'm not sure but you should look at `iwpriv`. Your goal is is to force the use of wifi B IMO

Comment: Tried 'iwpriv' on both AP and Client side, it says 'no private ioctls'.